# htaccess rewrite regex not matching conditions

Tags: regex, .htaccess

My current rule only matches if there is a trailing / after the first capture group OR if there is not trailing / after the second capture group

How to I make my rule match all of these

```
domain.com/staff     <-does not work
domain.com/staff/    <-works
domain.com/staff/1   <-works
domain.com/staff/1/  <-does not work
```

current rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)?$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
^([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*))?/?$
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/xR0lC5/1)

---

I changed the `.`s to `[^/]`s, made the entire `/(.*)` section optional, and then added an optional trailing slash.